# Why am I getting warning NU1507 with Central Package Management even with Package Source Mapping set?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I'm trying out the new [Central Package Management](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-central-package-management/) feature in NuGet.

As stated in the documentation, if you use multiple NuGet sources (which I use), it is now required to configure the Package Source Mapping in a `nuget.config` file, otherwise you should get a `NU1507` warning.

My simplified file tree is this:

- `MySolution.sln`
- `Proj1.csproj`
- `MyLibrary\` (this is an external repository with all my shared projects)

  - `Directory.Packages.props`
  - `nuget.config`
  - `Proj2\` (an example library project)

    - `Proj2.csproj`

Here is the `Proj1.csproj` content:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);MyLibrary\**\*</DefaultItemExcludes>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is `Directory.Packages.props`:

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageVersion Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="2022.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is `nuget.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear/>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"/>
        <add key="Custom NuGet" value="https://nuget.mydomain.net/"/>
    </packageSources>

    <packageSourceMapping>
        <packageSource key="nuget.org">
            <package pattern="*"/>
        </packageSource>
        <packageSource key="Custom NuGet">
            <package pattern="MyNamespace.*"/>
        </packageSource>
    </packageSourceMapping>
</configuration>
```

and `Proj2.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

[In the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied) the `MyLibrary\nuget.config` should be used when restoring the packages because it is in the parent directory of `Proj2.csproj`, and actually it works when I build the solution via `dotnet build`, but when I build it in Visual Studio I still get the `NU1507` warning.

I know that I could work around the issue by copying the `nuget.config` file in the same directory as the solution file (the warning goes away), but I have hundreds of projects that include the `MyLibrary` directory and I'd like to keep all the configuration centralized.

Moreover it works as expected when it's built from the command line, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems like correct from your configure file.But MS doc has mentioned this note:**Central package management is in active development**. You can provide any feedback you may have at [Nuget/Home](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues)

Here’re suggestions you can have a try to check :

1 check your visual studio version and this feature is available for Visual Studio 2022.17.2 and later.Because older tooling will ignore central package management configurations and features.See more information please refer to doc:[CPM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management)

2 If you are unable to onboard to Package Source Mapping but want to use central package management, can suppress the warning. Please refer to doc:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1507</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

3 use  `dotnet nuget list source` to get package source list and check whether they are enabled.

[image]

Comment: Hi, does it work for you? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
I've submitted an issue to the Nuget repo: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12371
Unfortunately it seems impossible to achieve what I have in mind because Nuget only reads nuget.config files from the solution dir and up.

Comment: @DouXu-MSFT or anyone: Why is multiple package sources even an issue? Is the implication that the nugets in different package sources could be different? I'm not following.

Comment: Here is the answer to the question, "Why is multiple package sources even an issue?" It tackles a security attack vector of Supply Chain Attack, Dependency Confusion (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/security-best-practices, https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610).

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Visual Studio:

Tools->Options->Nuget Package Manager->Package Source Mapping

- Click "Add"
- Enter: "Microsoft.*"
- Select => nuget.org

Result:
[image]

You can also remove local refences and/or other references.

Comment: what if i get this error in Azure pipeline?